# How do I add adjustable * to format ssn in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with Xsl and I was trying to add * in SSNs and wasn't sure how to go about it. I have done some research and concat() might be my answer but not sure how I could add *'s in there? Some SSNs are 4 characters long and some are 9 characters and some are just empty.

Example XML

```
<information>
    <secondBranch>
        <xsl:if test="Check = N">
        <SSN>771717771</SSN>
    </secondBranch>
    <secondBranch>
        <xsl:if test="Check = Y">
        <SSN>9991</SSN>
    </secondBranch>
    <secondBranch>
        <xsl:if test="Check = N">
        </SSN>
    </secondBranch>
</information>
```

Example XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <title>
            </title>
            <body>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        SSN
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/information/secondBranch">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </body>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to make them look like this

```
SSN
771717771
*****9991
*********
```

What I am getting is this

[image: Picture of output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
<tr>
    <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
</tr>
```

try:

```
<tr>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('*********', string-length(SSN)+1)"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
</tr>
```

---

### Added:

To output only `SSN` values with `Check` values of `"Y"`, change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/information/secondBranch">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/information/secondBranch[Check='Y']">
```

Comment: What if I want to check if         
(<Check>Y</Check>)
Check is 'Y' or 'N"

I was doing
<xsl:if test="Check = N">
              <xsl:text>SSN was removed </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I have to remove SSN completely if check says N.

Comment: NVM took me a while but I had to add single quotes

<xsl:if test="Check = 'N'">

Comment: Use a *predicate* (see the addition to my answer).